# How to align content horizontally using Flexbox?

Tags: html, css

[Example Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1oBHV.png) Don't worry about the look of it. I'm trying to align the input and the anchor horizontally with the logo using flexbox. Example attached. The logo will be on the right and the input with the anchor will be on the left but all horizontal.

```html
<div class="small-12 cell footer-logo-container">
    <a href="#">
        LOGO
    </a>
    <div class="footer-email">
        Sign Up for the Rock River Report Here
        <input class="footer-input" type="email" placeholder="email">
        <a href="#" class="link">
            <div class="link-text">
                SUBSCRIBE
            </div>
        </a>
    </div>
```

Comment: Hi and welcome! you tagged the question with CSS, it seem to me that you need a CSS solution but you didn't add your attempt. In other words - what is your question...?

Comment: Oh sorry, I didn't have any css. I'm not worried about the look being the same as the picture but just wondering how to create that using flexbox. Question is changed.

Comment: Ok. first you should modify your question after you read this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask . Second, try reading this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/. Useful website for most of your CSS. If I understood what you wrote correctly you could use this code:

```css
    .footer-logo-container {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row-reverse;
        justify-content: space-between;
    }
    
    .footer-email {
        display: flex;
    }
```

```html
<div class="small-12 cell footer-logo-container">
      <a href="#">
         LOGO
      </a>
      <div class="footer-email">
        Sign Up for the Rock River Report Here
        <input class="footer-input" type="email" placeholder="email">
        <a href="#" class="link">
            <div class="link-text">
                SUBSCRIBE
            </div>
        </a>
    </div>
```

Comment: How would I have the "Sign Up for the Rock River Report Here" text above the input but everything is aligned like your solution?

Comment: Use a label (check this link on how to use a label https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/label ). Put both the label and the input in a div with display: flex; and flex-direction: column;

Answer (score 0):

use the following css code, it should work fine:

```
.footer-logo-container{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row-revers;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
}
```

Comment: How so? In what way?

Answer (score 0):

In flexbox there is three important concepts: `flex-direction`, `align-items` and `justify-contents`.
`flex-direction` establishes the main-axis, thus defining the direction flex items are placed in the flex container.

In your case you need a flex container which should have `display: flex` style and you need to set `align-items: center` and `justify-content: space-between`.
You can change the order of your elements in html based on your design.

CSS:

```
.footer-logo-container{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="small-12 cell footer-logo-container">
    <a href="#">LOGO</a>
    <div class="footer-email">
        <p>Sign Up for the Rock River Report Here</p>
        <input class="footer-input" type="email" placeholder="email">
        <a href="#" class="link">
             <div class="link-text">SUBSCRIBE</div>
        </a>
    </div>
 </div>
```

CSS -

```
.footer-logo-container{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row-revers;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
}
.footer-email > p {
    display: inline-block;
 }
.footer-email > input {
   display: inline-block;
 }
.footer-email > a {
   display: inline-block;
 }
```

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/az2e0sud/9/)