# Align content horizontally next to div using flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm relatively new to HTML and CSS and am **trying to use CSS flexbox to align two divs horizontally** instead of it positioning the second div underneath the first or just having the second one just hide behind the first one.

I've tried answers from
[this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57365039/how-to-align-content-horizontally-using-flexbox) and many others that all suggested to use `justify-content` to horizontally align the content but it's just not working for me. [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/5vg8mruf/) is the code that I'm struggling with.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Many thanks,

Michael

EDIT:

Sorry for the confusion, to clarify, what I want is the text aligned horizontally to the right of the other div coloured grey. I should also say that I have tried using float with no success.

Comment: What do you need to achieve? You want the heading test is to be centered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just add this `float:left;` to sidebar class style . after this two div align horizontally ,if i understand what you need to achieve.

[image]

Comment: hello, sorry for the misunderstanding. What I want to achieve is to have the text horizontally aligned to the right of the other div coloured grey. I have tried using float with no success.

Comment: hmmm,see it now